# JavaScript namespacing and this/that scope

Tags: javascript

I am working on namespacing some applications and I am not understanding scope within a namespace.

```
(function (App) {
    App.Test = function(props){
        var that = this;

        var letter = "A";

        function init(){
            console.log("Round 1 ::::::::::::::::::::");
            console.log("     letter:",letter);
            console.log("that.letter:",that.letter);
            letter = "B";
            that.letter = "C";

            console.log("Round 2 ::::::::::::::::::::");
            console.log("     letter:",letter);
            console.log("that.letter:",that.letter);
        }
        function logLetters(){
        }
        this.letter = letter;
        init();
    };

})(window.App = window.App || {});

var app = new App.Test();

console.log("Round 3 ::::::::::::::::::::");
console.log(" app.letter:",app.letter);
```

Output

```
Round 1 ::::::::::::::::::::
letter: A
that.letter: A
Round 2 ::::::::::::::::::::
letter: B
that.letter: C
Round 3 ::::::::::::::::::::
app.letter: C
```

In Round 2 why doesn't `(letter === that.letter)`?

When I update `that.letter` why doesn't `letter` get updated and vice-versa?

if I want to have "Publicly" do i just need to declare them with this?

```
this.letter = "A";
```

Comment: In JavaScript, primitives (like numbers) are passed by _value_. Apart from this your `letter` property has nothing to do with the local `letter` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is [pass/call/assign **by value**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value). That means that a variable or property will always contain a *value*, but never a *reference to a variable*. I.e. assigning a new value to a variable or property does not change the value of another variable or property (exceptions are global scope and `with` scopes, where the variable bindings are connected to an object).

Example:

```
var foo = 42;
var bar = foo;
foo = 21;
console.log(bar); // 42
```

`bar` *does not* have a reference to `foo`. Instead the *value* of `foo` is copied to `bar`. Thus changing `foo` or `bar` later on does not impact the other variable.

Compare that to PHP where we can actually assign a variable by [*reference*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) using a special operator:

```
$foo = 42;
$bar = &$foo;
$foo = 21;
echo $bar; // 21
```

---

Applied to your example:

When you do `that.letter = letter`, you are copying the *value* of `letter` to `that.latter`. Now both bindings have the same value.

Later when you assign `letter = "B";` and `that.letter = "C";`, you are assigning new values to the variable and the property and now they have different values.

I might be missing something from your question, but I don't see how the issue has anything to do with `this` or namespaces in particular.